# Insert Statement error returned message "the driver cound't identify inserted rows"

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, odbc, linked-server, openquery

I am transferring the data from the local SQL server to a remote (PostgreSQL) table using a Linked server (ODBC). This works perfectly as long as I stick with Select query but fails with Insert, Delete, etc.
Error :

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DDL_PUYAML1_64" returned
> message "the driver cound't identify inserted rows". Msg 7343, Level
> 16, State 2, Line 75 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
> "DDL_PUYAML1_64" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

I have tried with Single Value but nothing changes.

As suggested [Error messages when you perform an UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE Transact-SQL statement on a remote table by using the OpenQuery function: "7357" and "7320"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-messages-when-you-perform-an-update-insert-or-delete-transact-sql-statement-on-a-remote-table-by-using-the-openquery-function-7357-and-7320-fa7315c4-638c-e529-44b4-bbd55dba8947) here, I have tried with column names instead of "*" and tried putting where 1=0 as well.

Any suggestion/feedback is appreciated.
Thank you!

**EDIT:** PFB the code

```
Insert openquery([DDL_PUYAML1_64],'select sn1,encl,encl_model from ws_sls_core.dd_enclosures_forarsdashboard_v1 where 1=0 ')
select sn1,encl,encl_model from #temp1
```

Comment: Please show relevant code

Comment: Hi @Charlieface , I have added the code in the question now. Thank you

Insert openquery([DDL_PUYAML1_64],'select sn1,encl,encl_model from ws_sls_core.dd_enclosures_forarsdashboard_v1 where 1=0 ')
select sn1,encl,encl_model from #temp1

Comment: Why not just do a straight linked server insert `Insert [DDL_PUYAML1_64].YourDatabase.ws_sls_core.dd_enclosures_forarsdashboard_v1 (sn1, encl, encl_model) select sn1, encl, encl_model from #temp1`

Comment: I have tried this and the error is same.

Comment: In SSMS tool > Object Explorer > Server objects > Linked Server check if the instance of the database is properly created or not. Check the connection string here and the connection string in your remote db.

Comment: It is too late for you, but someone else might benefit. Linked server in SQL server failed for me as well. For postgreSQL, I solved the issue, instead of trying linked server in SQL server, using FDW in postgreSQL.